# Swift UITableView Index Out of Range Error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am running a Firebase app in Swift. Here I am fetching Followers and Following Users. In cases where the user has just signed up, the app crashes as there may be no follower/following users yet. I have tried everything I can think of to handle the error, and all are not helping. My question is :
1. How can I avoid this crash?
2. Is there any way I can put an image or a button instead of blank tables that will redirect them to follow other users?

Below is the code :

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InProfileCell", for: indexPath) as! ConnectionsCell

        if currentIndex == 1 {
            let user = followerusers[indexPath.row]
            cell.showFollowersUsers(val: user)
            print("follower")
        } else {
            let user = followingUsers[indexPath.row]
            cell.showFollowingUsers(val: user)
            print("following")
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if currentIndex == 0 {
            return followingUsers.count
        } else {
            return followerusers.count
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
```

Comment: What is `currentIndex`? You should use the `indexPath` that's given in each function

Comment: On what line does the crash occur?

Comment: @Paolo `currentIndex` is just a variable that notifies which Segment I am in. I am using a custom segment controller view

Comment: @CharlesSrstka I am receiving a `Index Out of Range` in `let user = followingUsers[indexPath.row]`

Comment: @Paolo Code Updated

Comment: reload table view after segment changes not before. In `func didSelect(_ segmentIndex: Int)`

Comment: @Ryan worked Like charm! Not quite sure why didnt this work when I tried a bit back. Cheers mate.

Also, Is there any way I can just blank this empty table out and have a button that can take me to other pages

Comment: There are multiple ways to show alternative view instead of empty table view. The simplest is hide table view and add alternative view. Or you can use `tableView.backgroundView`. `tableView.tableHeaderView` is one possible spot as well.

Comment: Your currentIndex is different in both tableview methods!

Comment: You are comparing 0 and 1!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic in your `numberOfRows` and `cellForRow` is inconsistent. Your `numberOfRows` states that

```
if currentIndex == 0 {
    followingUsers
} else {
    followerUsers
}
```

However, your `cellForRow` is inconsistent with this because it states that

```
if currentIndex == 1 { //NOTE THAT YOU ARE USING 1 HERE INSTEAD OF 0
    followerUsers
} else {
    followingUsers
}
```

Now when the `currentIndex` is 2, the `numberOfRows` will return count of the `followerUsers` but the `cellForRow` would try to access the values of `followingUsers` (instead of `followerUsers`). That is the reason you are getting index out of range.